# XCode4:SCM repository configuration

Tags: svn, version-control, osx-lion, xcode4.2

I have upgraded my mac os snow leopard to Lion OS and upgraded xcode3 to xcode4. Previously SCM repository was configured with svn server and working fine .Now after upgrade repository configuration is not working for Xcode4. 
If any one has already faced this issue and configured SCM repository for Xcode4, please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

1. Open Xcode and select Window / Organiser.
2. Select Repositories
3. Bottom left, click the +
4. Add the details of the SVN server. Like this: svn://www.servername.com/directory
5. Where asked for Trunk Branches and Tags (leave empty for now).
    
   now use the “Terminal” program to make a connection to SVN.
6. Create a test.txt file with some simple message in it. Save it in your documents folder on your mac.
7. Open Terminal
8. Type “svn import /Users/yourname/Documnets/test.txt svn://www.servername.com/directory -m “initial import” –username yourname
9. You will be prompted with your existing user for your user password. At this point, if your mac user name does not match the configured SVN user name. Just hit enter. It will then prompt of a user. Type the new SVN user name, then enter. Then the configured SVN pass and enter.
10. You will likely see something that says. “svn://www.servername.com/directory already exists” – Ignore that!
11. Close Xcode
12. Open Xcode again and return to the Optimizer / Repositories and with luck, your server will list on the left hand side, and show the ROOT and any folders on the SVN server.
13. Click back on the server name in the left hand column.
14. Type in the names of the Trunk Branches and Tags folders. We chose to use these names to make it easy. They need to be setup on the SVN server by the administrator. They ARE case sensitive.
15. The text.txt file can be deleted from the server through Xcode if desired.
16. Close the terminal session.

For detail refer [this](http://xcodeapple.blogspot.in).